# Setting mainclass for stage task

Tags: sbt

I'm creating an sbt project I'd like to deploy to heroku. The build pack for heroku uses the 'stage' task to compile the project. For my project I want to set the 'mainClass' that gets built into the unix executable that 'stage' creates so that heroku starts things correctly. I've found plenty of help on how to set the main class for the 'run' and 'package' tasks and that works great for me. I just can't find any directions on how to set it so that the 'stage' task picks it up. Is there any documentation on this that someone could point me to? (I'm using sbt version 0.13.5)

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably uses `mainClass in Compile` in `stage` (guessing `stage` is from the sbt-native packager).

As for the documentation, it mentions `mainClass` once: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/archetypes.html

Note that `mainClass` is equal to `mainClass in Compile` for most builds as compile is set as the default configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried: val workerMainClass = Some("org.myorg.catalog.index.CatalogIndexWorker")

mainClass in (Compile, run) := workerMainClass

mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := workerMainClass, but with the same results. In the meantime I've found a work-around for what I wanted to do by just pointing the defined process in my foreman 'proc' file to the class file I'm interested in and running it with 'java -cp ...'. It would still be nice to find a way to do it through the unix executable though.

Comment: Yes, I have tried  `mainClass := workerMainClass` as well. Same result.

Comment: @RyanKeller What plugin supplies the `stage` task? Maybe you can set up an example project on Github

Comment: I believe it is the _sbt-native-packager_ plugin that supplies the stage task. I'll work on setting up a project on Github as you suggested and post here when it's up.

Comment: I've created a simple project to show what I'm currently trying. [TEST PROJECT here](https://github.com/ryanskeller/alternateMainClass) This version sets the main class in the manifest of the generated jar file, but does nothing for the generated scripts at 'target/universal/stage/bin'.

Comment: @RyanKeller Apparently the Play plugin set's the default setting at `compile:mainClass`, so in order to override it, you need to use `mainClass in Compile := Some("worker.Worker")`

Comment: That did the trick. I'm now able to use the unix script files to execute my application.Thank you for the help.